# Android google maps API-key 'REQUEST_DENIED'

Tags: android, maps

I want to use distance matrix by google. When I use postman for checking my URL, it works fine, it returns correct JSON. When I do the same thing in my android app, I receive request denied. I'm not restricitng my key, i do not autorize it, I want it to be public and I want to use it everywhere if possible. There are post 5 years old saying that I might be using web browser Api key, but I cannot find specific, android app manual for android api key generator. What I am doing wrong?
[request denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGtUK.jpg)

Another thing, I cannot change anything in my account, but I dont think these options matter since they are optional.
[Failed to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIVEf.jpg)

I'm using Retrofit:

```
@GET("maps/api/distancematrix/json")
Call<DistanceResponseModel> getDistanceModel2(@Query("origins") String origins,
                                              @Query("destinations") String destinations,
                                              @Query("key") String key);
```

- I've activated APi in CloudConsole
- i'm adding key to the request
- APIs are no restricted or unauthorized
- I also added key to manifest and gradle with [THIS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) manual

Answer (score 0):

I was using http instead of https in my serivce generator. So yeah, lol.